# load a screen widget in different state(scroll to widget or display default mode from top widget)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to conditionally mutate a screen widget(HomeThreadScreen()) from another screen(screen code below) in such a way that I can open the same widget(HomeThreadScreen()) in default state and in custom state(scroll to widget).

**for example:**
This is how I navigate to the new screen:

```
Widget getSelectedMenu() {
      switch (selected) {    
        case DrawerSelectables.servicesMenu:  // open and scroll to service widget
          return HomeThreadScreen(
            drawerState: openDrawer,
          );
        case DrawerSelectables.buyNow:
          return Sales(
            drawerState: openDrawer,
          );
        case DrawerSelectables.authScreen:
          return const AuthScreen();
        default:
          return HomeThreadScreen(  // destroy previous state and open in default
            drawerState: openDrawer,
          );
      }
    }
```

**What I've tried:**
1.*created an extra constructor in the target widget and added a GlobalKey parameter, I set it as a key argument to the widget I want to jump to then conditionally called Scrollable.ensureVisible(key.currentContext!); in build method when key is not null.*

Works but the state doesn't change when I switch to the default widget(it stays in the services widget instead of viewing from top widget).

2.*Also tried using initState() and calling WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() with my scrolling logic. works but there's don't know how to conditionally manage the state.*